# How to convert Generic.List values into extension method

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, extension-methods, generic-list

I am using Linq to Entity , Linq query returning a **ToList**() and storing multiple rows in ***DataSourcesModel*** class. Later i am using foreach to iterate items and store values in ***DataSourcesModelDTO***, till here working fine.

Now question is **DataSourcesModelDTO** ***dto*** storing only one row value.
I am expecting it should store multiple row value. How to achieve this in ***extension*** method?

** var `datasoruceModeltDTO = DataSourcesDTOTransformers.ToDTO(result);`**

```
public static class DataSourcesDTOTransformers
    {
        public static DataSourcesModelDTO ToDTO(this List<DataSourcesModel> model)
        {
            if (model == null) { return null; }
            var dto = new DataSourcesModelDTO();
            ToDTO(model, dto);
            return dto;
        }
        public static void ToDTO(List<DataSourcesModel> model1, DataSourcesModelDTO dto)
        {
            foreach (var model in model1)
            {

                dto.DataSourceConfigID = model.DataSourceConfigID.ToString();
                dto.DataSourceID = model.DataSourceID.ToString();
                dto.Name = model.Name;
                dto.server = model.server;
                dto.LastModified = model.LastModified;
                dto.Instance = model.Instance;
            }


        }
    }



[DataContract]
    public class DataSourcesModelDTO
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string DataSourceID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string DataSourceConfigID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string server { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime LastSync { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You are missing : DataRow newRow = dto.Rows.Add(); newRow.DataSourceConfigID = model.DataSourceConfigID.ToString();

Comment: No, I am not using dataTable here. I have added my DTO class.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var model in model1)
{

    dto.DataSourceConfigID = model.DataSourceConfigID.ToString();
```

You are setting the properties of the same `dto` object every time in the loop. I would rearrange your  `toDTO` methiod to either:

- take in a single `DataSourcesModel` object and return a single `DataSourcesModelDTO` object (calling the method from within a loop or Linq query), or
- take in an `IEnumerable<DataSourcesModel>` and return an `IEnumerable<DataSourcesModelDTO>`

> How to achieve this in extension method?

Not sure why you need an extension method, but the appropriate signature would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataSourcesModelDTO> ToDTOCollection (this IEnumerable<DataSourcesModel> model)
```

I'll let you work out what the implementation would be.  Hint: You could create a `List<DataSourcesModelDTO>` within the method and populate it with new objects the same way you are now.